# How to go through a list on two different worksheets comparing values using VBA

Tags: vba, worksheet

I am trying to match 2 columns in one worksheet with 2 (or potentially more) columns in another worksheet.

I have posted a sample of my worksheet data which hopefully gives a good description of what I have been trying to do for the past week. I think I am on the right track but I don't know how to properly reference between the two worksheets.

What I would like to do is look at Location 1 column, then see if that location references with my RefSheet in either location 1 or location 2.

If it does, I want to see if Location 2 then matches up in the somewhere in the same row on the RefSheet. If there is a match, I want to highlight the cell/cells yellow and give the ID number from RefSheet.

If there is no match I want to either highlight it red or no highlight.

```
Sheet All
A       B               C               D
ID  Location 1  Location 2  Given ID
1   West    North   
2   North   South   
3   South   East    
4   East    West    
5   East    East    
6   South   West




Sheet RefSheet
A       B               C   
ID  Location 1     Location 2
1   West            North
2   West            East
3   South           East
4   South           North



What it should look like on the original Worksheet
A               B               C           D
ID          Location 1  Location 2      Given ID
1(Yellow)   West            North           1
2(Yellow)   North           South           4
3(Yellow)   South           East            3
4(Yellow)   East            West            2
5(Red)      East            East    
6(Red)      South           West
```

Here is my terrible Code

```
    Sub roadfinder()

    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim nextIntersection
    Dim RefSheet As Worksheet
    Dim list As Worksheet

    Set intersections = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RefSheet")
    Set crashes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lngLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngCounter = 2 To lngLast
        With Cells(lngCounter, "B")

            For Each rCell In RefSheet.Range("B1", RefSheet.Cells(RefSheet.Rows.Count, 1)).Cells
            lCnt = lCnt + 1

                'I wasn't sure what to put as a reference to
                If .Value = "" Then
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6

                End If

            Next rCell
        End With
    Next lngCounter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: On the fifth reading I start getting this vague idea, that you want to match an unordered pair of Sheet ALL!(Location1, Location2) to an unordered pair of Sheet RefSheet!(Location1, Location2). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. There will have to be two loops. One that goes through the main loop and another to go through RefSheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's easy enough to do by a simple excel formula without any programming.
Just put into cell 2 of your column for Given ID the following as an **array formula**:

```
=SUM(SIGN((B2=Refsheet!$B$2:$B$5)*(C2=Refsheet!$C$2:$C$5)+(B2=Refsheet!$C$2:$C$5)*(C2=Refsheet!$B$2:$B$5))*Refsheet!$A$2:$A$5)
```

And copy this formula through the whole column
(I assume your input locations are in columns B, C, and your RefSheet range is in A2-C5, like you provided in your example)
You'd better make named ranges on your Refsheet, though, so that formula will become:

```
=SUM(SIGN((B2=Ref_Loc1)*(C2=Ref_Loc2)+(B2=Ref_Loc2)*(C2=Ref_Loc1))*Ref_ID)
```

(Remember, it should be an array formula).
Once you have the ID you can easily make Conditional formatting of your input cells based on whether the ID is 0 (meaning not found) or not.
It is essential for refsheet location pairs to be unique,for ID to be numeric and not zero.

Comment: I placed that code in and it works for ID 1 and 3 but for 2 and 4 it comes up with 0. Also I don't understand that code at all. Would it be too much to ask you to walk me through that?

Comment: It doesn't work for values 2 and 4 for you because bold font is not enough to make people read it. I can't find a way to make these words red coloured and 30px font on this site, so I'll just repeat: make it an `array formula`

Comment: Sorry I forgot you had to hit ctrl shift enter for the array. Could you explain what the code is doing now?

Comment: I think the formula is pretty self-evident. Expressions like B2=Refsheet!$B$2:$B$5 yield 1 for every cell where there's a match and 0 otherwise. Product of those expressions gives you 1 for matching pairs, then you add 1's for matching reversed pairs. SIGN function is needed if you have a matching pair like (East, East) which will match twice and give you 2, sign function reduces it to 1. Then you multiply it by ID which will give you IDs for cells that yielded 1 in previous expression. There must be only one matching pair, otherwise you'll get the sum of IDs for all matches.

Comment: There will be multiple matching pairs. For example it should be expected to find 4 East West in the main document. My plan was to, once I assign the group ID number, to sort and see how many pairs of each there are.

Comment: I hope there will by only _one_ matching pair on Refsheet for them? Otherwise what ID are you going to take?

Comment: Yes there will be only one matching pair on RefSheet, but there may be multiple on the original "All" sheet.